# ListView different template when selected

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create a different template for a list view item when it is selected, however I couldn't find anything about doing this.

What is the best way to select a template based on whether the listview item is selected or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to select a template based on whether the listview item is selected or not?

Changing the default template and customize animation inside `VisualState` is the right way.

1. Copy and paste the default ListViewItem styles and templates in your project, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx)
2. Change the brush in the `Selected` and `PointerOverSelected` visual states:

**`SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush` in the `Selected` visual state:**

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Change to:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**`SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush` in the `PointerOverSelected` visual state:**

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Change to:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Check my completed sample [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/ListViewTemplateApp1)

**-----Update(09/27/2016)-----**

> How would I use this to change the DataTemplate of a ListBoxItem when it's selected

If you need to switch `DataTemplate`, you might change it from code behind.

1) Append a DataTeemplate in the page's resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="->" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

2) Add handler for `SelectionChanged` event:

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.Items>
            <ListViewItem Content="One"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Two"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Three"></ListViewItem>
        </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

3) Change DataTemplate from code behind

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Assign DataTemplate for selected items
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            ListViewItem _lvi = item as ListViewItem;
            _lvi.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["dataTemplate1"];
        }
        //Remove DataTemplate for unselected items
        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            ListViewItem _lvi = item as ListViewItem;
            _lvi.ContentTemplate = null;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Have updated my demo: [LINK](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/blob/master/ListViewTemplateApp1/ListViewTemplateApp1/BlankPage1.xaml.cs)

Comment: How would I use this to change the DataTemplate of a ListBoxItem when it's selected?

Comment: @Mrten Please check my updated reply   **Update(09/27/2016)**